# How to play a sound once, but not ONLY once?

Tags: python

I have a logical problem which I didn't succeed solving yet. I'm working with an object detection app and I wanted to add voice prompts to it. If I just use the `playsound` function, it keeps on repeating the voice prompt over and over when it is in a specific category.
I want my program to play the sound only once when it is in a specific category (i.e: `person`, `tv`, `airplane`, `apple`, etc). But when it re-enters that category, the sound has to play again once.

I tried adding a boolean value (`play_person_sound`) to it. It only plays once but the problem with this is that it never plays again when it re-enters that category. So for example: if the program detects a person first, it plays `'person.wav'`, if it then detects a tv, it plays 'tv.wav', if it detects a person after the tv again, it doesn't play `'person.wav'` any more because `play_person_sound` is set to `False`. I tried adding another switch and this works for one category: `person`, but since there are 80 categories this feels undoable.

Does anybody know a clever way to make this work?

Below there is a code snippet:

```
play_person_sound = True
switch = 1
...

if name[0][0] == 'person':
    if play_person_sound:
        play_person_sound = False
        playsound("sounds/person.wav")
    if switch == 0:
        switch = 1
        playsound("sounds/person.wav")

elif name[0][0] == 'tv':
    switch = 0
    playsound("sounds/tv.wav")

elif name[0][0] == 'airplane':
    playsound("sounds/airplane.wav")

elif name[0][0] == 'apple':
    playsound("sounds/apple.wav")

elif name[0][0] == 'backpack':
    playsound("sounds/backpack.wav")
```

Answer (score 2):

The normal approach is to keep a variable with the last category and play the sound only when the category is different from it:

```
category = name[0][0]
if category != last_category:
    last_category = category
    playsound("sounds/" + category + ".wav")
```